# UIViewController inheritance not working with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, swift, xcode6

I'm coding a new app using Swift, and I've found a problem that I can't solve. I have a class ParentViewController, which inheritates from UIViewController. Apart from that, I have a view controller called MainMenuViewController, which inheritates from ParentViewController. The MainMenuViewController has a xib file with the same name, I've set the file's owner type to MainMenuViewController and it allows me to link the outlets, but when I try to set the file's owner view outlet to the view that I have in Interface Builder, this outlet doesn't appear in the Interface Builder, so if I run the app it crashes because it can't find a view for that view controller.

If I change the inheritance of MainMenuViewController to UIViewController instead of ParentViewController, the outlet of the file's owner view appears perfect and everything works perfect..

I can't understand why with the inheritance of ParentViewController doesn't work, because it inheritates from UIViewController itself...

Any ideas?? I'm using XCode 6 beta 6

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's a bug of the xcode 6 beta 6, because if I change the inheritance to UIViewController directly instead of ParentViewController, and I set the view outlet, and after that I revert the change and it inherits from ParentViewController, it works.. The outlet still not appearing, but the app works.